# Why I have to add dependencies with parent pom?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, dependency-management

I have this piece of code from pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

When I hover over some dependency I have this message: `The managed version is #someNumber The artifact is managed in org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.3.RELEASE`. Is this message considered ok? If yes, why I have to declare dependencies I'm using if `parent` already has all of them?

If I had to declare my dependencies anyway, what is the advantage of having a `parent`? Only for managing versions of dependencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parent POM doesn't (necessarily) tell your project to include all of those dependencies; it says that *if* you need the dependencies, use this version.

For example, some Spring Boot projects are completely message-based and don't need the Web pieces--no MVC, no servlet container. It would be wasteful to include all of that for a project where it's not needed.

For more information, you can look into [the documentation for Maven dependency management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management).